# Defining a default method in interface gives syntax error "Unable to interpret DEFAULT"

Tags: abap

I'm on an 7.40 system and try to demonstrate default methods in interfaces.  For that, I copied the [example code of the ABAP Keyword Documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_740_index_htm/7.40/en-US/abapmethods_default.htm) into a report. Minimal code:

```
INTERFACE intf.
  CLASS-METHODS m1 DEFAULT FAIL.
  METHODS       m2 DEFAULT IGNORE
                   RETURNING VALUE(r) TYPE i.
ENDINTERFACE.
```

Surprisingly, that gives a syntax error

> Unable to interpret "DEFAULT". Possible causes of error: Incorrect spelling or comma error`.

I also tried to define the interface as global interface with the Source Code-Based view but to the same result.  The form-based view does not seem to offer a `default` option.

How to get it right?

Comment: What is the SP level? DEFAULT comes in SP08: https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_740_index_htm/7.40/en-US/abennews-740_sp08-abap_objects.htm

Comment: Uh, I was proud of myself having checked the release number before asking this question. But I did not check the SP level. Yes, the SP level of my system is SP04.
Thanks. Please post your comment as answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new addition DEFAULT is valid from 7.4 SP08 only:

https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_740_index_htm/7.40/en-US/abennews-740_sp08-abap_objects.htm

Comment: I'ts a shame that information is not present on the main page of the language feature. This way, it is easy to miss.